# Is there a function or tool to get the size of a row in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-astra

Can I get more info about the column of certain row in Cassandra ? Like the size of a row or a column?

Or some information about the size of the row like using a tool like nodetool ?

Maybe something based on the primary key / clustering key ?

Because in Astra Cassandra I have only access to CQL Console ...

```
<uat>root@cs01:~# nodetool cfstats mykeyspace.series;
Total number of tables: 249
----------------
Keyspace : mykeyspace
        Read Count: 18547
        Read Latency: 0.36771666576804873 ms
        Write Count: 3147
        Write Latency: 0.11854496345726087 ms
        Pending Flushes: 0
                Table: series
                SSTable count: 11
                Space used (live): 17919747207
                Space used (total): 17919747207
                Space used by snapshots (total): 0
                Off heap memory used (total): 16091840
                SSTable Compression Ratio: 0.13888102122935306
                Number of partitions (estimate): 177144
                Memtable cell count: 0
                Memtable data size: 0
                Memtable off heap memory used: 0
                Memtable switch count: 7
                Local read count: 11399
                Local read latency: NaN ms
                Local write count: 1753
                Local write latency: NaN ms
                Pending flushes: 0
                Percent repaired: 0.0
                Bloom filter false positives: 1
                Bloom filter false ratio: 0.00000
                Bloom filter space used: 282544
                Bloom filter off heap memory used: 282456
                Index summary off heap memory used: 81176
                Compression metadata off heap memory used: 15728208
                Compacted partition minimum bytes: 36
                Compacted partition maximum bytes: 14530764
                Compacted partition mean bytes: 622218
                Average live cells per slice (last five minutes): NaN
                Maximum live cells per slice (last five minutes): 0
                Average tombstones per slice (last five minutes): NaN
                Maximum tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 0
                Dropped Mutations: 0
----------------
```

Many thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that Astra DB is a fully-managed Cassandra instance, you will not be able to run operator commands such as `nodetool` against it. That's just the nature of fully-managed services.

The best you can do is to look at the metrics of your DB's health dashboard. However, this won't really help you if you're not able to write the data to your DB.

As a friendly note, you shouldn't ask multiple questions in the same post. I would suggest you create a new post for your first question that includes (1) sample data, (2) sample schema, and (3) minimal code which replicates the problem. Cheers!